# What's a placeholder? Why do we need to define placeholder data type for generics?

Tags: swift, generics

```
func inspect <SomeType> (value: SomeType) {
    print ("Received \(type(of: value)) with the value of \(value)")
}
```

I am following a tutorial from Pro Swift book, but I can't understand why do we need the `<SomeType>`. It seems unnecessary. What added information are we giving to the compiler?

The author himself says:

> Note the use SomeType: there's one in angle brackets directly after
>   the function name, and one to describe the value parameter. The first
>   one in the angle brackets is the most important, because it defines
>   your placeholder data type: inspect() means "there's a
>   function called inspect() that can be used with any sort of data type,
>   but regardless of what data type is used I want to refer to it as
>   SomeType." So, the parameter value: SomeType should now make more
>   sense: SomeType will be replaced with whatever data type is used to
>   call the function.

I don't get it nor understand what does *placeholder data types* means?

**Edit:**
Or with a better example

```
  func inspect <T> (value1: T, value2: T) {
        // ....
    }
```

My question: I know that T will enforce value1 & value2 to have same type, so what is the use case of `<T>`.

Comment: So you have not understood what a generic is in the first place. Your question is really "What is a generic?", which is kind of broad for Stack Overflow. Would it help you to read a different discussion? Here's mine: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_generics

Comment: Well, you might just mean "I don't find this a very compelling example, as there is no good reason to use a placeholder here." If that's what you mean, I agree. In that case, that's what you should have asked! Otherwise, I stand by my analysis: use of a placeholder data type is what generics are all about, and if you truly do not understand what "placeholder data type" means, you truly do not understand what a generic is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With credit to both answers provided.

Let's just say you wrote your code as below (*without* the `<T>`) and see what happens:

```
func inspect (value1: T, value2: T) {

    // some operation with value1, value2
}
```

What is the type of `T` here? Is `T` a class a struct or an enum? Or it's a generic type as you intended? The **compiler doesn't know**. It will give the following error:

> error: use of undeclared type 'T'

Just because you wrote something with `T` it's not going to magically transform into a generic.

To better illustrate the problem see this snippet:

```
func inspect (value1: T, value2: T) {
    // some operation with value1, value2

    var x = T() 
    var m = U() 

}

class T {
    var name = "someName"
}
class U {
    var name = "someName"
}
```

`var x = T()` <-- Do you expect this to be an instance of class `T` or a generic type?

Without `<T>`, `x` is *expected* to be an instance of type `T`. If you haven't defined `T` as a type, if not then you'd just get an error.

---

Which is why in real code you see using `<T>`. The actual type will come into the 'place' where type `T` was 'holding' onto before. :

```
func inspect <T> (value1: T, value2: T) {
    // some operation with value1, value2

    var x = T() // error!
    var m = U() // No error

}

class T {
    var name = "someName"
}
class U {
    var name = "someName"
}
```

Actually doing `x = T()` creates an error:

> 'T' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers

If this error wasn't spotted by the compiler then the `T` inside the function would be non-generic and would come from the class definition or just unknown...

The reason we do‌ `<T>` is to create a local vanilla type and avoid having  wrong expectations from outside. (Though if you constrain it, then it's different)

Why does Swift supersede the *generic* `T` over the *class* `T`? I assume it's because Swift gives priority to the local scope.

Comment: Also recommend everyone to see [Getting error: String is not convertible to 'T'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58792877/getting-error-string-is-not-convertible-to-t/58792878#58792878)

Answer (score 5):

> What added information are we giving to the compiler

We are saying: "Dear compiler: I'm not going to tell you right now what the type of `value` will be, which seems an unusual thing to do when declaring a function. But trust me, compiler, you will know what type it is when you see how this function is *called*, elsewhere in this program."

Answer (score 3):

It may be confusing because that function is not a very good example of generics. That function could be rewritten as a non-generic and still do exactly the same thing:

```
func inspect (value: Any) {
    print ("Received \(type(of: value)) with the value of \(value)")
}
```

They become more useful in other cases. For example, if it were something like

```
func inspect <T> (value1: T, value2: T) {
    // ....
}
```

That tells the compiler that `T` can be any type, but that the two arguments must be of the **same** type. If you had used `Any` here, the arguments could be any type and could be of different types.

Or maybe

```
func inspect <T> (value:T) -> T {
    // ....
}
```

That says that the function takes an argument of any type **and returns something of the same type**. Again, if you used `Any` here, the declaration wouldn't require that the return type match the argument type.

Comment: I agree. This was just poor pedagogy. That's why my book starts with a much more compelling case of a generic, namely how Optional works.

Comment: Very informative comparision with `Any`. I think you just explained how value1 & value2's types are kept in sync. Can't that just be achieved by `func inspect (value: T, value: T) {}` or is that just by saying `<T>` we are creating a medium type right on go which would help the compiler better understand

Comment: If you leave out the `<T>`, the compiler will complain that there's no such type as `T`. The `<T>` says that you're using `T` as a generic type in this function.

Comment: matt: I don't think it's poor pedagogy, it's just a half-quote from the poster. I'm the author of the book in question, and the *very next sentence* after OP's quote says, "As you'll see in a few minutes, placeholder data types are also used for return values…" because that's exactly what I go on to show. However, clearly it's confused the poster, so I'll edit the text to make it clearer.