# Generic understanding issue

Tags: swift, alamofire

I was reading Alamofire example, below is the function declaration is not clear to me what does this mean:  `Response<T, NSError> -> Void`

```
  public func responseObject<T: ResponseJSONObjectSerializable>
      (completionHandler: Response<T, NSError> -> Void) -> Self {
  ////
 }
```

Comment: The `completionHandler` is a closure (a function), that takes a `Response<T,NSError>` object as its input and returns a `Void` as its output.

Comment: Response<T,NSError> , what is this ??

Comment: Response<T> represent generic  but Response<T,NSError> is not clear .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we need to define placeholder data type for generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39856681/why-do-we-need-to-define-placeholder-data-type-for-generics). (make sure you see the *accepted* answer). You'll either find an answer or would be able make an edit and ask something different.