# Getting error: String is not convertible to 'T'

Tags: swift, generics

This code compiles and works fine:

```
class Numbers {
    func operateOn<T>(_ num1: T, _ num2: T, do task: (T, T) -> ()) {
        task(num1, num2)
    }
}

let n = Numbers()
n.operateOn(1,2) {
    print(($0 + $1) * 10)
}

n.operateOn("l","ll") {
    print(($0 + $1))
}
```

Yet for for following code does not compile.

```
func process<T> (add: String, completion: (T) -> () ) {
    completion("k") // ERROR
}
```

Yet I get the following error:

> 'String' is not convertible to 'T'

I tried passing an `Int`, but I just got another error:

> 'Int' is not convertible to 'T'

Can't an `Int` or a `String` satisfy a generic requirement that doesn't have any constraints?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your code needs to work *for any `T`*. E.g. if `T` is `Int` then `completion` has type `(Int) -> ()`, it's completely legitimate to call

```
n.process<Int>("") { $0 + 1 }
```

and `completion("k")` would have to do `"k" + 1` which doesn't make sense.

This is going to be the same in basically any language with generics (C++ is different because it uses templates for the same purpose instead).

Answer (score 0):

> Can't an `Int` or a `String` satisfy a generic requirement that
> doesn't have any constraints?!

Sure it can. But that's not the reason the compiler is giving you an error.

Think about it, what happens if you constrain a generic function/parameter **within** the **function body** itself?! It will no longer be a generic function!

Imagine if you had wrote your `operateOn` function as such:

```
class Numbers {
    func operateOn<T>(_ num1: T, _ num2: T, do task: (T, T) -> ()) {
        task("k", num2) // add two strings
    }
}
```

Would you say that `T` is generic? Or that it's of type `String`? If you made it a `String` then can `num2` be any generic type it wants to be? It can't!

If it's of type `String` then it's no longer *generic*. Since the compiler can't allow that it will throw that error.